# Call validation directive function in the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

Im trying to call the validation function from directive in the controller. Is it possible?

My directive is something like this:

```
app.directive('evenNumber', function(){
  return{
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(checkForEven);
      function checkForEven(viewValue){
        if (parseInt(viewValue)%2 === 0) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('evenNumber',true);
        }
        else{
          ctrl.$setValidity('evenNumber', false);
        }
        return viewValue;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I want to call the function checkForEven from the controller.

```
$scope.copyFileContentToEditor = function(){
  $scope.code = $scope.content;
  // TODO call the checkForEven directive function to validate the $scope.code
}
```

Is it possible to do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: From evenNumber directive controller?

Comment: I want to call the checkForEven function of the directive 'evenNumber' in the $scope.copyFileContentToEditor function

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define a link between your controller and your directive to get them know each other.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World'; // this is just used for your directive model, it is not the part of the answer

  $scope.vm = {} // define this to create a shared variable to link the controller and directive together.
});

app.directive('evenNumber', function(){
return{
require:'ngModel',
scope: {'vm': '='},
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){

  function checkForEven(){
    alert('I get called.')
  }

  scope.vm.checkForEven = checkForEven; // once the directive's method is assigned back to "vm", so you could trigger this function from your controller by call this vm.checkForEven;



}}})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-model="name" even-number vm="vm"></div>
```

[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ykbeo0iMJJKEjzakrWQK?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Add the function as a property of the ngModel controller:

```
app.directive('evenNumber', function(){
  return{
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(checkForEven);
      //ADD checkForEven to ngModel controller
      ctrl.checkForEven = checkForEven;          

      function checkForEven(viewValue){
        if (parseInt(viewValue)%2 === 0) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('evenNumber',true);
        }
        else{
          ctrl.$setValidity('evenNumber', false);
        }
        return viewValue;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Then name the form and input element:

```
<form name="form1">
    <input name="input1" ng-model="vm.input1" even-number />
</form>
```

The controller can then reference it where it attaches to scope:

```
$scope.copyFileContentToEditor = function(){
    $scope.code = $scope.content;

    //CALL the function
    $scope.form1.input1.checkForEven($scope.vm.input1);

}
```